# how to display part of next page view?

Tags: flutter, networking, dart, swipe

Hello I am developing a kind of social network. In each post I would like the user to be able to swipe to the left to display more parameters. I use a page view but it doesn't really create an extension but changes pages completely. Anyone have a solution?
Thank you in advance.

At the begging : 
[At the begging :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUxg9.png)

What I want : 
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebept.png)

What I Have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTyUf.png)

Here is my code :

```
Container(
    height: height,
    child: PageView(controller: pageController, children: [
      news_container_origin(),
      secondView(),
    ]),
  );
```

Comment: check this out maybe it can help => https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageView has a Boolean parameter pageSnapping that allows you to see a fraction of the next page if you want, it's true by default (it will snap to only show one page)

```dart
   Container(
      height: height,
      child: PageView(controller: pageController,
        pageSnapping: false, //change it to false
        children: [
          news_container_origin(), 
          secondView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```